# Twitter bootstrap webjar doesn't reference less files correctly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, webjars

I am using a twitter bootstrap webjar : `"org.webjars" % "bootstrap" % "3.3.6"`. I then do include it in my template : `<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">`
however, I get a lot of 404 coming from the less files, by instance :

```
http://localhost:9000/assets/lib/bootstrap/css/less/mixins/image.less 404
```

When opening my folder containing the webjar librairies, I have seen that the less folder isn't in `assets/lib/bootstrap/css/less` but in `assets/lib/bootstrap/less`

Since the reference to this folder is done inside the files fetched from my webjar, how could I set the correct path to the less folder ?

Comment: Where is the reference to the `.less` files coming from?

Comment: bootstrap.map file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately this is due to Bootstrap having path references that are incorrect.  So it can't be fixed in the WebJar.

```
tail -n 1 META-INF/resources/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css
/*# sourceMappingURL=bootstrap.css.map */
```

In `bootstrap.css.map` you see the incorrect path references:

```
{"version":3,"sources":["bootstrap.css","less/normalize.less" ...
```

BTW: The map files are only loaded when the Developer Tools are open so this shouldn't be an issue for normal users.